# How does postgres query planner work on partitioned tables?

Tags: postgresql, database-partitioning

We have a postgres 11 database with tables having a quite big number of rows, so we use postgres declerative partitioning to ensure query performance.

Today while wirting a database function I noticed some strange behaviour of the postgres query planner:

In this particular case we have two tables `track.track` and `sensor.location`.
The function shall return all locations for a given track.

The relation between `track.track` and `sensor.location` is given by a `user_vehicle_id` and a time range.

`sensor.location` is partitioned monthly by range using the column `time`

A query for this problem could look like this:

```
WITH single_track AS (
    SELECT 
        start_time, stop_time, user_vehicle_id 
    FROM 
        track.track 
    WHERE 
        id = 1350000744800)

SELECT * 
FROM 
    sensor.location as l, single_track as t
WHERE 
    l.time >= t.start_time AND 
    l.time <= t.stop_time  AND
    l.user_vehicle_id = t.user_vehicle_id
```

I would expect that the query planer only looks at those partitions of `location` which match the given time frame from `start_time` to `stop_time`.

Instead it performs a Bitmap Heap/Index scan on all partitions:

```
Nested Loop  (cost=8.59..9308018.00 rows=722021 width=106) (actual time=1.796..2.296 rows=1025 loops=1)
  CTE single_track
    ->  Index Scan using track_pkey on track  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=24) (actual time=0.023..0.024 rows=1 loops=1)
          Index Cond: (id = '1350000744800'::bigint)
  ->  CTE Scan on single_track t  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=24) (actual time=0.027..0.029 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Append  (cost=0.15..9286171.84 rows=2183770 width=82) (actual time=1.750..1.998 rows=1025 loops=1)
        ->  Index Scan using location_p2011_01_pkey on location_p2011_01 l  (cost=0.15..8.83 rows=1 width=136) (never executed)
              Index Cond: (("time" >= t.start_time) AND ("time" <= t.stop_time) AND (user_vehicle_id = t.user_vehicle_id))
        ->  Seq Scan on location_p2011_02 l_1  (cost=0.00..7.71 rows=1 width=82) (never executed)
              Filter: (("time" >= t.start_time) AND ("time" <= t.stop_time) AND (t.user_vehicle_id = user_vehicle_id))
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on location_p2011_03 l_2  (cost=643.94..3370.03 rows=2087 width=114) (never executed)
              Recheck Cond: (("time" >= t.start_time) AND ("time" <= t.stop_time) AND (user_vehicle_id = t.user_vehicle_id))

        ...

        ->  Index Scan using location_p2020_10_pkey on location_p2020_10 l_117  (cost=0.15..8.83 rows=1 width=136) (never executed)
              Index Cond: (("time" >= t.start_time) AND ("time" <= t.stop_time) AND (user_vehicle_id = t.user_vehicle_id))
        ->  Index Scan using location_p2020_11_pkey on location_p2020_11 l_118  (cost=0.15..8.83 rows=1 width=136) (never executed)
              Index Cond: (("time" >= t.start_time) AND ("time" <= t.stop_time) AND (user_vehicle_id = t.user_vehicle_id))
        ->  Index Scan using location_p2020_12_pkey on location_p2020_12 l_119  (cost=0.15..8.83 rows=1 width=136) (never executed)
              Index Cond: (("time" >= t.start_time) AND ("time" <= t.stop_time) AND (user_vehicle_id = t.user_vehicle_id))
Planning Time: 11.046 ms
Execution Time: 4.144 ms
```

While playing around I discoverd, that using the same query but passing the times explicitly:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYSE
WITH single_track AS (
    SELECT 
        start_time, 
        stop_time, 
        user_vehicle_id 
    FROM 
        track.track 
    WHERE 
        id = 1350000744800)

SELECT * 
FROM 
    sensor.location as l, single_track as t
WHERE 
    l.time >= '2016-04-12 18:04:59' AND 
    l.time <= '2016-04-12 18:22:49'  AND
    l.user_vehicle_id = t.user_vehicle_id
```

produces the expected behaviour:

```
Nested Loop  (cost=9.00..2111.73 rows=141 width=102) (actual time=0.085..2.408 rows=1025 loops=1)
  CTE single_track
    ->  Index Scan using track_pkey on track  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=24) (actual time=0.017..0.018 rows=1 loops=1)
          Index Cond: (id = '1350000744800'::bigint)
  ->  CTE Scan on single_track t  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=24) (actual time=0.021..0.022 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Append  (cost=0.56..2099.99 rows=328 width=78) (actual time=0.060..2.081 rows=1025 loops=1)
        ->  Index Scan using location_p2016_04_pkey on location_p2016_04 l  (cost=0.56..2098.35 rows=328 width=78) (actual time=0.058..1.994 rows=1025 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (("time" >= '2016-04-12 18:04:59'::timestamp without time zone) AND ("time" <= '2016-04-12 18:22:49'::timestamp without time zone) AND (user_vehicle_id = t.user_vehicle_id))
Planning Time: 4.709 ms
Execution Time: 2.494 ms
```

Can anyone explain this behaviour and help me how to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be too complicated for the PostgreSQL executor.

I'd suggest trying

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    sensor.location as l, single_track as t
WHERE 
    l.time >= (SELECT start_time FROM track.track WHERE id = 1350000744800) AND 
    l.time <= (SELECT stop_time FROM track.track WHERE id = 1350000744800)  AND
    l.user_vehicle_id = (SELECT user_vehicle_id FROM track.track WHERE id = 1350000744800)
```

Then PostgreSQL knows at least that there will only be a single value.

If that still doesn't work, split the query in two parts:

- First, get the values from `track.track`.
- Then construct a query using the results and execute that.

Comment: I already tried this.  Same behavior. Also this would cause 3 queries on track. I don’t get your second solution, isn’t that what I do in the with query?

Comment: No, you are trying to run it in a single statement. If you run it in two statements, the second statement would have the values as constants and so can certainly prune the unnecessary partitions.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: What's unclear? You run the query from the `WITH` clause. You get three values. You construct a query on the partitioned table using these values as constants. You execute the query.

Answer (score 0):

I also tried this, which may be close to what Laurenz Albe suggested. I wasn't able to confirm that this causes the right behavior, as `EXPLAIN ANALYSE` does not show the query plan of a `psql` funtction.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION location_from_track_id(
    _track_id bigint)
    RETURNS SETOF sensor.location 
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

AS 
$BODY$
DECLARE 
    _user_vehicle_id bigint;
    _start_time timestamp without time zone;
    _stop_time timestamp without time zone;

BEGIN

SELECT 
    user_vehicle_id, 
    start_time, 
    stop_time 
INTO 
    _user_vehicle_id,
    _start_time,
    _stop_time
FROM 
    track.track
WHERE id=_track_id;

RETURN QUERY
SELECT *
FROM sensor.location 
WHERE
    time BETWEEN _start_time AND _stop_time AND 
    user_vehicle_id = _user_vehicle_id;

END;
$BODY$;
```